# Rewriting the URL in a Web API Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

In my first Web API project, I'm using attribute routing to direct incoming requests to my product details logic in what I believe to be a straight forward manner:

```
[Route("v1/inventory/{stock}/add")]
public IHttpActionResult PostAddSku(string stockNumber)
{
    // stuff
}
```

But my customer wants to invoke the logic with a URL formatted as so:

```
http://localhost:57863/api/v1/inventoy
```

And in the request body:

```
action=add&stockNumber=ABC
```

I must accommodate my customer and recognize that I need to rewrite his incoming url to my expected structure, but am not sure where the best place to do that is.  Do I do it in RouteConfig.cs? and if so, what is the most efficient way to inspect that action variable in the request body (which has 4 or 5 acceptable values each of which map to a particular action method in my controller?

Comment: You can check http://grandhah.blogspot.in/2015/07/url-rewriting-in-mvc-4-attribute-routing.html for detailed url writing in web-api